# Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = r < m$, then $A$ has a row of zeros.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = r < m$, then the reduced row-echelon form of $A$ has a row of zeros.

How do I start to prove this?

Comment: The statement is false. Consider for example the $2 \times 2$-matrix whose entries are all equal to $1$.

Comment: No its not in RREF form if all entries are 1

Comment: Then you should add to your question that you assume that the matrix $A$ is in RREF form.

Comment: According to what we learn in class, the rank is only calculated after the matrix is converted to RREF form

Comment: @aazzaaaa Whether or not it is calculated then, it exists whether it is in RREF or not.

Comment: I disagree with the two down-votes.  The fact that a question is founded upon an error is not a reason to down-vote it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: All matrices have a rank, but it is easier to calculate once it is in RREF. However, $A$ is not *equal* to its RREF (in general).

Comment: So this statement is true, right. If we are considering the RREF

Comment: Yes, if you assume that $A$ is in RREF form, it is true.

Comment: @aazzaaaa : It is not only matrices in RREF form that have ranks.  All matrices have ranks.  Elementary row operations do not change the rank, so one way to find the rank of a matrix is to use those operations to put it into RREF form, and then the rank is the number of non-zero rows.  But the rank of the original matrix is the same as the rank of the matrix that you get in RREF form.

Comment: So, then it shouldn't matter whether I stated it was in RREF form or not. What does that have to do with the question then?

Comment: @aazzaaaa : You said if the rank is less than the number of rows, then it has a row of zeros.  That is true of matrices in RREF form, but there are matrices having no row of zeros whose rank is less than the number of rows.  If you had said that if a matrix in RREF has a rank less than its number of rows, then it has a row of zeros, then that would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself what will happen with the rows, once you find RREF(A).

1. What will happen to the first $r$ rows? ... They will contain a pivot(after a possible permutation of rows) and will thus be non-zero.
2. What will happen to the other $m-r$ rows(at least 1, since $m-r>0$)? ... They(it) will contain no pivot and hence will be eliminated by the elimination process, therefore they(it) will contain only zeros.

That would be my approach.

As a side note, although there are no limitations between $n$ and $r$, we should have $r\le n$, because otherwise we can't $fit$ the pivots in the matrix!